# Error en NodeJs Express: requiere una funcion middleware

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, javascript-objeto

Estoy aprendiendo NodeJS con Express, y estoy intentando desarrollar un API pero al momento de ejecutar el index.js recibo el siguiente error

---

> /Users/user/Desktop/node/curso-node-express/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:458
>         throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
>   TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object
>       at Function.use (/Users/user/Desktop/node/curso-node-express/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:458:13)
>       at Function. (/Users/user/Desktop/node/curso-node-express/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:220:21)
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at Function.use (/Users/user/Desktop/node/curso-node-express/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:217:7)
>       at module.exports.app (/Users/user/Desktop/node/curso-node-express/src/routes/v1/index.js:6:9)
>       at Object. (/Users/user/Desktop/node/curso-node-express/src/index.js:7:1)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)

---

Ya he buscado varias soluciones y ninguna me ha funcionado.

Este es el código que estoy usando

**user.controllers.js**

```
const createUser = (req, res) =>{
    res.send.json({status: 'OK', message: 'user-created '});
}

const delUser = (req, res) => {
    res.send.json({status: 'OK', message: 'User Deleted'});
}

const getUser = (req, res) => {
    res.send.json({status: 'OK', data: []});
}

const updateUser = (req,res) => {
    res.send.json({status: 'OK', message: 'User updated'});
}

module.exports = {
    createUser, delUser, getUser, updateUser
};
```

---

**products-controllers.js**

```
const createProduct = (req, res) => {

}

const getProduct = (req, res) => {

}

const delProduct = (req, res) => {

}

module.exports = {
    createProduct, getProduct, delProduct
};
```

**users-routes.js** (Aquí es en donde creo que me marca el error)

```
const express = require('express');
const userController = require('../../controllers/v1/users-controllers');

const router = express.Router(); 

router.post('/create', userController.createUser );
router.post('/update', userController.updateUser);
router.post('/delete', userController.delUser);
router.post('/get-all', userController.getUser);    

module.exports = router;
```

**products-routes.js**

```
const productController = require('../../controllers/v1/products-controllers');
```

**index.js** (Este index es el que esta dentro de las rutas con el cual manejo mis rutas)

```
const productsRoutes = require('./products-routes');
const userRoutes = require('./users-routes');

module.exports = app => {
    app.use('/api/v1/users', userRoutes );
    app.use('/api/v1/products', productsRoutes);
}
```

**index.js** (es el que ejecuto para iniciar la aplicación)

```
const express = require('express');

const routesV1 = require('./routes/v1');

const app = express();

routesV1(app);

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log("Listening on 4000");
});
```

Comment: y que tienes en el fichero `./routes/v1`?

Comment: Dentro del fichero routes/v1 tengo index.js donde pongo las rutas, y tengo products-routes.js y users-routes.js

Comment: puedes poner el codigo de ese fichero?

Comment: Lo puse en la pregunta, ahí estan los componentes, products-routes.js, user-routes.js y el primer index.js ¿no se si se te refieras a eso?

Comment: el código del fichero`./routes/v1` no lo has puesto. Entiendo que haces un `require('./index')` en `./routes/v1` pero no se como registras las rutas.

Comment: ohhh ok ok, ese v1 es una carpeta, en el curso que estoy viendo a como lo entiendo yo el primer index.js que puse es el que maneja las rutas, dentro de ese fichero v1, esta products-routes y user-routes y los mando llamar a index.js para manejar las rutas, asi es como lo entiendo yo, la verdad apenas le estoy entendiendo a Express

Comment: Tus módulos `user-routes.js` y `products-routes.js` no son [middleware válidos](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#middleware-callback-function-examples) que puedas usar en el método [`app.use()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use).

Comment: @MauricioContreras puedes indicar lo que esta mal porque yo no veo el error.

Comment: @MauricioContreras ¿cual es la manera correcta de declarar los middlewares entonces?

Comment: ¿El archivo `products-routes.js` está así de incompleto? Si solo es eso lo que tienes en dicho archivo, esa puede ser la causa del problema. Uno de los archivos de rutas está mal, pero si no subes el archivo completo no puedo ayudarte. Por eso mi comentario, ya que el error indica que estás pasando un objeto en vez de una función y por lo que aportas es muy probable que sea en tu archivo `product-routes.js` donde esté el problema. Si aún no has escrito la lógica de dicho archivo, entonces es mejor que comentes la linea donde lo usas: `//app.use('/api/v1/products', productsRoutes);`. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras si era lo que me dijste, tenia incompleto el controlador, comente todo lo de products y me funciono otra vez, muchas gracias